# Apache2 : How to configure different/multiple websites in Dedicated IP

Tags: apache, hosting, apache-config, dedicated-server, multiple-sites

I have 5 websites which is to be hosted on a single dedicated server.

```
### Many documents(apache2) provide help to achieve this 
site1.com > should access /var/www/html/site1
site2.com > should access /var/www/html/site2
```

---

But what I want is the below scenario.... How do I achieve this(below) in Apache2?

```
### So for example (eg. IP:  54.33.123.21) :
54.33.123.21/site1 > should access /var/www/html/site1
54.33.123.21/site2 > should access /var/www/html/site2
```

I need to use only the IP. Not any domain name for now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Apache server DocumentRoot to /var/www/html and... that's it.

Comment: You have to restart apache server in order to refresh the configuration. Also, what kind of error do you getting?

Comment: I have done all i can. it is a dedicated IP. So 54.33.123.21/site1 should access DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1...

Comment: If you need to run these sites as a different virtual hosts, you have to somehow distinguish them from each other - one way that is open for you, it's to configure virtual hosts with different ports.